# Styling when a child class appears inside itself

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm trying to find an elegant solution to styling a child element, when it has the same class as the parent element.

I suspect Javascript will be required to make this work, although I've also explored ways to do it with SASS variables, without success.

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="film parent">
  <div class="film child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am writing out all of the possible options in a long css command like:

```
.film .film,
.music .music,
.art .art {
  color: red;
}
```

etc.

This isn't ideal, as new class names will appear in here over time, and I'd like a catch-all style to account for those.

Comment: With the given example, it is unclear why you could/would not just use `.parent .child { color: red; }`

Comment: Unless you want JavaScript to generate or manipulate stylesheet rules (so that you could _create_ the necessary `.foo .foo` parts of your selector), it would make more sense to add a class for formatting purposes to those childs via JS then. Loop over all relevant elements, and for each of their classes, check if the parent has that class, too - if so, add a class to the child to apply the special formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use CSS Selectors to style the parent and child tag easily

You can use `:first-child` selector to select the first child of the tag

```
film:first-child{
    color:red;    
}
```

here it will select the first child of the tag with a class film and will change the colour to red

You can read more about CSS Selector
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

Comment: the `film` or `art` will be dynamically generated. Not just select the first element sorry.

Comment: @JamieHutber could you please elaborate

Comment: Wello, he is asking to dynamically generate styles, your solution does not produce any styles.